# Red lines in Android Studio with Ampiri

Tags: android, android-studio

I have used Ampiri integration in my app.
I copy paste all the code from their android sdk integration wizard for banner ads into my code. What bothers me is that Android Studio can not find that listener and view in the red letter.

So what is that I miss? Is there any problems on my code? If not what should I do to resolve this issue? Please help me.

Following is my code:

1. I’ve implemented the AdEventCallback using:

`import com.ampiri.sdk.listeners.AdEventCallback;`

2. and call it from main activity inside onCreate as describe in my code below:

   ```
    public abstract class MainActivity extends AdCallbackActivity implements AdEventCallback {...}
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           FrameLayout adView = (FrameLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
           StandardAd standardAd = new StandardAd(this, adView,“MY_ADUNIT_ID",BannerSize.BANNER_SIZE_320x50, adListener);
           standardAd.loadAd();
   ```

Comment: post your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check my comments inline for each error.

1. **view.findViewById(R.id.ad_view)**

   If the ad_view is in the current Activity layout set by setContentView, you don't need to add "view."

   i.e.

   `findViewById(R.id.ad_view)`
2. **adListener**

   Please implement an event listener interface AdEventCallback, referencing to [our integration page](https://github.com/ampiri/ampiri-android-sdk#ad-events-handling-callbacks).

Comment: Looks like the code in the integration wizard needs to change. 
Thanks for the suggestion, findViewById(R.id.ad_view) worked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, If you will have the AdEventCallback methods in your AdCallbackActivity.java file.

please try the code below.

```
 StandardAd standardAd = new StandardAd(
                this, adView, "3dfbb889-3bcd-4c34-82ae-8fcb539c3b25",
                BannerSize.BANNER_SIZE_320x50, this);
```

If it doesn't work, please send me your MainActivity and AdCallbackActivity to [suppport@ampiri.com](http://mailto:suppport@ampiri.com).